# How to configure email accounts in android account manager programatically?

Tags: android

I want to write a new application to add Email accounts programatically from the inputs like username,password and other info.

Is there any way to do that? Please share the sample code if any.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Sam

Answer (score 0):

I have been researching this as well. It seems that this is NOT possible with the current device administration API. Hopefully Google releases a new API soon (then of course, we'll be left to deal with the problem of devices that have not upgraded).

Comment: It am also looking for a similar solution and haven't found anything. Kindly keep this thread posted, if you have found/manage to find anything in the meanwhile